# OnShareTargetActivated on Windows10

Tags: c#, navigation, windows-phone-8.1, share, windows-10

I want to get text from the external environment.

```
 protected override void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
    {
        var frame = new Frame();
        frame.Navigate(typeof(Pages.WorkPage), args.ShareOperation);

        Window.Current.Content = new MainPage(frame);
        Window.Current.Activate();
    }
```

My MainPage Construcor:

```
 public MainPage(Frame frame)
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.splitView.Content = frame;

        ((Frame)splitView.Content).Navigate(typeof(Pages.WorkPage));
    }
```

.. and `OnNavigatedTo` in my WorkPage like this

```
   protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Parameter == null) return;

        var shareOperation = (Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ShareTarget.ShareOperation)e.Parameter;
        if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.Text))
            txtMessages.Text = await shareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();
    }
```

How can I change `OnShareTargetActivated` to get my `OnNavigatedTo` working properly?

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to load `MainPage` and navigate its `frame` to `WorkPage`, and meanwhile pass the shared text to `WorkPage`. To do this, you don't need to pass a new `Frame` to `MainPage`, [Page.OnNavigatedTo](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.controls.page.onnavigatedto.aspx) method will be invoked when the Page is loaded and becomes the current source of a parent Frame. So you can navigate your frame of `MainPage` and pass the shared text in the `OnNavigatedTo` method of `MainPage`, and in `OnShareTargetActivated` you can just navigate to `MainPage`.

You can change `OnShareTargetActivated` just like this:

```cs
protected override async void OnShareTargetActivated(ShareTargetActivatedEventArgs args)
{
    Frame rootFrame = Window.Current.Content as Frame;
    if (rootFrame == null)
    {
        // Create a Frame to act as the navigation context and navigate to the first page
        rootFrame = new Frame();

        // Place the frame in the current Window
        Window.Current.Content = rootFrame;
    }
    rootFrame.Navigate(typeof(MainPage), args.ShareOperation);
    Window.Current.Activate();
}
```

and `MainPage` Construcor like this:

```cs
public MainPage()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();

    //this.splitView.Content = frame;

    //((Frame)splitView.Content).Navigate(typeof(WorkPage));
}
```

Add `OnNavigatedTo` of `MainPage` like this:

```
protected async override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter is Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ShareTarget.ShareOperation)
    {
        var shareOperation = (Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.ShareTarget.ShareOperation)e.Parameter;
        if (shareOperation.Data.Contains(Windows.ApplicationModel.DataTransfer.StandardDataFormats.Text))
        {
            var data = await shareOperation.Data.GetTextAsync();
            ((Frame)splitView.Content).Navigate(typeof(WorkPage), data);
        }
    }
    else
    {
        ((Frame)splitView.Content).Navigate(typeof(WorkPage));
    }
}
```

Change the `OnNavigatedTo` of your `WorkPage` like this:

```
protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Parameter != null)
    {
        var data = e.Parameter;
        txtMessages.Text = data.ToString();
    }
}
```

By the way, why you added the Windows Phone 8.1 Tag for this question? SplitView is not existing in WP8.1 .